# function call with shared pointer whose object should be const

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a variable `a` whose type is `A`.

```
A a;
```

I want to call a function which takes a const reference of type `A` as an input argument.

```
fun(const A &a);
```

After some code changes I decided it is best to change the type of variable `a` to `std::shared_ptr<A>`

```
std::shared_ptr<A> a;
```

What is the best way to change function `fun` so that I make sure that object `a` is never changed (it should remain const)?

should `fun` remain as it is and I should call it like:

```
fun(*a.get())
```

or is there any alternative? Somehow this feels ugly to me...

I guess simply changing `fun` to `fun(const std::shared_ptr<A> &a)` will not work because I want to make sure that the function does not change the underlying object and not the shared pointer.

I cannot use `std::shared_ptr<const A> a` because it is necessary to change variable `a` at some point.

Comment: `const std::shared_ptr<A> &` only makes the shared pointer const. The proper way to have a const A is to use a const A, so `std::shared_ptr<const A>`. But you should be able to convert a `std::shared_ptr<A>` into a `std::shared_ptr<const A>` -> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr (9)

Comment: Also a little bit to say that you don't want to change `a` and then at the end ou say that you want to change it...

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher He wants to make sure it is not changed in `fun()`.

Comment: Yes, it should not be changed in `fun()`

Comment: Then there is no problem with using `<const A>` as the argument of this function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was not aware that you can pass a `shared_ptr<A>` to a `shared_ptr<const A>` function argument.

Comment: Look at the cpp reference link 

Comment: Interesting reading: [gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `void fun(const A& a);` doesn't seem to have any implications on the lifetime of the argument, leave the signature as it is now (passing `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` as a function argument always suggests those lifetime implications). Call it like this:

```
auto a = std::make_shared<A>();

fun(*a);
```

This way, you can get around the wordy `*a.get()` and directly use the [dereference operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*) provided by `std::shared_ptr`.